# What is the name of the method for physically tilt your iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want my character to move left and right by tilt my iphone (physically). What is the name of the method?? Tips are welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do exactly use `CMMotionManager`.

Comment: I Understand UIAccelerometer is deprecated instead we use CMMotionManager?

Comment: Can you teach me how to use CMMotionManager or do you have any recommendations of tutorials?

Comment: Maybe this tutorial is useful for you: http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2014/04/howto-use-device-motion-sensors-to.html